# Show Adjuster Amount Only in Commerce

Tags: plugin-development, templating, plugin-craftcommerce, php

I have adjusters that dynamically add/remove costs to things like `baseShippingCost` and `baseDiscount`, and want to be able to specifically show the numbers for those adjusters on the cart page - not just the total `baseDiscount` or `baseShippingCost` number - as things like shipping costs, or coupons, are also bundled into those.

Here's the adjuster example from documentation, I'll use this as the example:

```
class BusinessLogic_TaxRemover implements Commerce_AdjusterInterface {

    public function adjust(Commerce_OrderModel &$order, array $lineItems = []){

    $myAdjuster = new Commerce_OrderAdjustmentModel();

    $order->baseDiscount = $order->baseDiscount - 5;

    $myAdjuster->type = "Tax Remover";
    $myAdjuster->name = "Australian GST Remover";
    $myAdjuster->description = "Removes the 10% GST";
    $myAdjuster->amount = -5.0;
    $myAdjuster->orderId = $order->id;
    $myAdjuster->optionsJson = ['lineItemsAffected'=>null];
    $myAdjuster->included = false;

    return [$myAdjuster];

    }

}
```

How would I access the `$myAdjuster->amount` in the template/twig file for the order? I've tried `{{ cart.myAdjusterName.amount }}` and I simply get the error "Craft\Commerce_OrderModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "**myAdjusterName**".

Does anyone know how to get this information? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access each adjuster and its respective amount via the `cart.adjustments` tag. Here's the example supplied with the templates from the commerce plugin (commerce/cart.html):

```
{% for adjustment in cart.adjustments %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ adjustment.type }}
        </td>
        <td><strong>{{ adjustment.name }}</strong><br>({{ adjustment.description }})</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ adjustment.amount|currency(cart.currency) }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you have set the `included` attribute of your Adjuster to true then it won't show up as an adjuster but only affect the cart amounts outputted (such as `baseShippingCost` and `baseDiscount`) so if you have something similar to the above already, that's why it won't be displayed. You can read more about the `included` attribute [here](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/adjusters).

Comment: Gotcha - I did notice I could find them in cart.adjustments but hate that I'd have to loop through them just to print the ones I need. After looking around I'm guessing this is the only way to access them from the cart model. Thanks for pointing it out!